# TypeError in validator node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, reactjs

I am getting following error while using validator for data.

```
TypeError: _validator2.default.isNull is not a function
```

I have installed validator using `npm install --save validator`  (version is validator@7.0.0)
Using validator in function as

```
import Validator from 'validator';

function validateInput(data) {
  let errors = {};

  if(Validator.isNull(data.email)){
    errors.email = 'Email needed';
  }
}
```

But when I navigate to installed validator module it is showing `isNull` function.But during validation it is throwing error.
Any help?

Comment: are you sure that validator provides isNull as a function.. I could not find it here :https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/src/index.js

and you can just use data.email === null check..right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can directly use email validator.

```
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';

validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com'); //=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, TypeError: _validator2.default.isNull is not a function because in validator(node modules) no isNull.js library. i think validator isNull is deprecated. alternative way is you change isNull with isEmpty. or you can write

> if (data.email == "" ) {
>       errors.email = 'Email needed';
>     }

hope may help you ;)